# Union and endianness without htonl/ntohl

Tags: c++, tcp, endianness

I want to parse a header of my TCP package that I receive.

Assume this is a header structure:

```
(2 bytes for commands) + (2 bytes for token) + (4 bytes for data length)
Example of package: 0x01 0x02 0x12 0x34 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x05
There 0x0102 is command, 0x1234 is token and 0x000005 is data length.
```

I want to parse this header in effective way on Windows platform. I made the next union for this header:

```
typedef union
{
    struct
    {
        uint16_t command;
        uint16_t token;
        uint32_t data_length;
    } field;
    char bytes[8];
} MyHeader_t;

MyHeader_t bar;
read_8_bytes(bar.bytes);
std::cout << bar.fields.token << std::endl;
```

Next I tried to copy package above to my `bytes` array. But network package is in big endianness and PC tries to read fields as little endianness. As result, my `token` field is equal to `0x3412` (and not to 0x1234).

How could I avoid this issue with separate endiannes?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Boost provides a library dedicated to endianess:

http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_61_0/libs/endian/doc/index.html

For example:

```
boost::endian::big_to_native_inplace(bar.field.command);
```

or by AndyG:

```
std::cout << boost::endian::endian_reverse(bar.field.token) << std::endl;
```

Note: This library has 3 ways to deal with endianness, you need to take time to chooce what is suitable for your case.

Comment: Would be nice to show an example also, how the OP's problem could be solved with that library.

Comment: `std::cout << boost::endian::endian_reverse(bar.field.token) << std::endl;`